# How do I write a code to display the month (column 1) of the highest demand (column 5)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to solve a problem that asks for which month the highest demand is found in. Demand is column E and Months are column A.
This is my current code so far.

```
Sub MaxDemandMonth()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim MaxVal As Long

    Set wsData = Worksheets("DATA")
    Set Rng = Range("E:E")
    MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
    Set Maxcell = Rng.Find(what:=MaxVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
    mDRow = Maxcell.Row

    MsgBox "Max Demand was Found in Month" & mDRow

End Sub
```

Comment: `Maxcell.EntireRow.Cells(1)` is the cell in ColA for that row.

Comment: Where would I put that line in the code?

Comment: Please include any error codes or sub-optimal results you have received from this code. Please also include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you can loop from first row to last row, declare variable to store your date and value, for first loop you store them to variable, the next loop you check if value is more higher from your variable value, store again your data, and after all loops finish, you alreade have the max value in certain date, and you then can extract the month

Comment: The month is in `Cells(mDRow, "A").Value`. Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to ensure that you are reminded to declare `mDRow As Long`.

Comment: `Dim mnth: mnth = Maxcell.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value: MsgBox mnth`